# Integral not defined in 0

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

My teacher proposed us the following challenge:

Provide conditions for the reals numbers $a$ and $b$ such that the following integral converges and compute the value:

$$
\int_0^c \left|\frac{1}{t^a}\right|^b dt,
$$
where $c>0$ but fix.

He mentioned that the integrand is well defined for some Lebesgue's spaces.

Already I tried to compute formally, obtaining:

$$
\int_0^c \left|\frac{1}{t^a}\right|^b dt=
\int_0^c \left(\frac{1}{t^a}\right)^b dt=
\left. \frac{t^{-ab+1}}{-ab+1} \right|_0^c = \frac{c^{-ab+1}}{-ab+1}.
$$

Do you have some advice?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If $c\gt0$, then the absolute value bars are unnecessary.

Comment: What happens if ab= 1.

Comment: See that for all $ab \ge 1$, the integral evaluates to a function that is asymptotic at $t = 0$. Moreover, its limit at $0$; $\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}{\frac{1}{t^{ab > 1}}} \to \infty$, hence is divergent.

Comment: @Dstarred is it divergent for ab<1 ?

Comment: If $c$ is real and $≠\infty$ then it is not.

Comment: @Dstarred could you recommend a reference to check this and learn more about it, please?